# Typescript argument check against a union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check if a string has a prefix that matches a union type, eg:

```
type Prefix = "ABC" | "DEF" | "GHI" ...;
const hasPrefix = (str: string): boolean => {
   // I want to check the first 3 characters of the string
   // And see if it matches any of the Prefix
   // Something like
   //  if (str.substr(0, 3) === Prefix)
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is how to use `Prefix` type with built-in methods, right? It seems like only custom logic, like in your comment, applies (type string, then a check).

Comment: Why would you want to check against a type instead of just an array of prefix strings? What's your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of TypeScript you can't dissect a union type. For your problem I would recommend an approach using `enum`s like so:

```js
enum Prefixes {
    "ABC",
    "DEF",
    "GHI"
}

const hasPrefix = (str: string): boolean => Prefixes[str.substr(0, 3) as any] !== "undefined";

console.log(hasPrefix("123")); // false
console.log(hasPrefix("ABC")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("DEF")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("GHI")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("GHII"));// true

const data = "ABC123";         // ABC123

console.log(hasPrefix(data));  // true
console.log(data);             // still ABC123
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTsAZgSwB7AM5QN4FgBQURUARAIIBCAwiQDQHGkAiAogGJ0PEkDiAEgEkSBAL4ECAYwD2IDABcoACwCGGeEjRQAvFAAU8uAC4oB5CADmASmMAjKVIA2wZSG0A+WAhToMAbQMAdBhgNga6AAy0UADMllCq8SAAngC6UACEWjokYCAAJhogwHkkANzi+NKyjsABDlLmuipqXmi6JACMAEzRJJaW5ZUyGDV1DU2q6t7tlDT9g1UjTmONzVNtJKwc85LDo-Wrk62o7fxCO0PVywcTLRonvILnAxWLCnnKcsrapLPdvYNdldajc1sddB8vhdFvtxpDlC98EA) a TypeScript playground of the above code.

---

Judging by your question you seem to be interested in a dynamic way to check for prefixes (the `...` characters imply this (?)). This got me thinking and came up with a solution using a `Set` data type. Consider this example:

```js
// Set data type ensures only uniques
type Prefix = string;
const prefixes: Set<Prefix> = new Set();

prefixes.add("ABC");
prefixes.add("ABC");
prefixes.add("DEF");
prefixes.add("GHI");

// No doubles here so we're good (note the double added ABC string)
console.log(prefixes);

// the typeguard
const hasPrefix = (str: any): str is Prefix => typeof str === "string" ? prefixes.has(str.substr(0, 3)): false;

console.log(hasPrefix(100));   // false
console.log(hasPrefix(0));     // false
console.log(hasPrefix(false)); // false
console.log(hasPrefix(true));  // false
console.log(hasPrefix(""));    // false
console.log(hasPrefix("123")); // false
console.log(hasPrefix("ABC")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("DEF")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("GHI")); // true
console.log(hasPrefix("GHII"));// true

const data = "ABC123";         // ABC123

if (hasPrefix(data)) {
    console.log(hasPrefix(data));  // true
    console.log(data);             // still ABC123
}
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/PTAEGUFMBdQEwIbQaaBPADpUkB2BnAVwCdJ9QB7XAGzVENwEsBHQsgWACh0tQAFUgDNGAD1ABeUPmjFGuAOYBuLgGMq00BiGiyALggwAPAMjCRAPgmhckAO4HoACgCUyzly2md+AHQI4cI4ARACCAEIAwkGuHtoiZH4BweFRMZyeZgn+gUEAIgCiAGLRbhneiTkA4gASAJIlXFwgoAByFPAUhABG1GSgABaQpFLttpAA5MPyFBRwoI64FNDY0IMd3b2g2ZBzKVIycvLOquoUvT7UFPKOZfH4aU1gqyuYkPKECMRwJwSw-Qj4ExmKyOaTEfQIXBoZz6MGgRjkIGiCSWHiQCiCfbECTiSRBMGHIKgAD8mjiCX++FBMh8RC6YMcAAYADSgADMzhhoEECGo+Egbh++DOkAuV0clKRIkcAEZGYzOYpQMrmjy+ZAhSKxddJXEmYrlYbVbz+ZrzpcdQCpY41fyDcb1WbRRaJVa9TI2AbQA7TZw1AQtS7dV5pUFoq5Dd6wLaNX7TubxcGzMEZQAmNnhpU+2P+4UJy2AvWhSKZqOoYhsJ3a12FkPBArFe1PCs5+POxNuutBGr1JvlytxgP5mvW7t1XuuZoe2NC2CIZBWYsRNMZpWRyPNFIrxqcRiYkd6+cITmgADeXEjucDHdryaPXqnLYvhqvw-va-Xn+a0kY1GooC3dMuAAXy4IA) the playground for that code.

Comment: In your first code snippet, using `typeof Prefixes[str.substr(0, 3)] !== "undefined"` [would be more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4725697/5784924)

Comment: @Nicolas thank you for your feedback, I updated the first example.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible at the moment just with built-in Typescript types.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579 and for reference to proposals: [How to define a regex-matched string type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445767/how-to-define-a-regex-matched-string-type-in-typescript)