# Typescript: String literal type with custom parameter`

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am attempting to define a string literal type that has a variable parameter in it.

e.g:

```js
type myStringType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | `d[${parameter}]`
```

I'd like the string `d[parameter]` to accept anything which resembles `d[foo]` or `d[bar]`

**Edited:**
added back ticks to template literal, though i'm not attached to this being a template literal and if there is another solution...

Comment: Did you mean to use a template string for “d”? If so, swap the single quotes to back ticks.

Comment: That seems like job for a regular expression, unless typescript offers special syntax for such things.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with a union type, here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445767/how-to-define-a-regex-matched-string-type-in-typescript) that unfortunately got a "not possible" answer.

Comment: I was hoping something new had come up. 

After a little extra research it seems this is coming in [typescript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Typescript 4.1, you can use [template literal types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#template-literal-types).

```
type parameter = "foo" | "bar"

type myStringType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | `d[${parameter}]`

// type myStringType = "a" | "b" | "c" | "d[foo]" | "d[bar]"
```

Comment: Yeah this is the correct answer as there is no real other solution until TS4.1 comes out.