# How can I map a patternProperties from json schema to a typescript interface

Tags: json, typescript, jsonschema

I am creating a typescript interface corresponding to a json schema. I have the following field in my json schema:

```
         "styles": {
            "title": "Style Definitions",
            "description": "Style definition",
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        { "$ref": "#/definitions/definition1" },
                        { "$ref": "#/definitions/definition2" }
                    ]
                }
            }
         }
```

I want to create my interface something like this:

```
interface Styles {
    [key: string]: Definition1 | Definition2;
}
```

But this isn't right and doesn't capture the correct meaning of the json schema.
Can someone tell me how to do this?

How can I write this thing in my typescript interface?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same question. In my situation, I had been hoping that the [openapi-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript) library would support converting schemas which use `patternProperties` into typescript interfaces but it does not appear to support this presently. (See [the issue](https://github.com/drwpow/openapi-typescript/issues/754) I opened).

The situation with `patternProperties` really boils down to whether we can restrict a string in Typescript only to values that match a given regex. [This is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445767/how-to-define-a-regex-matched-string-type-in-typescript). The bottomline is that ***regex restrictions are not directly supported*** (though there is an open [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) for that functionality to be included), so being able to ***generically*** convert schemas which utilize `patternProperties` to an equivalent Typescript interface is ***not possible currently***.  For simple patterns there is something pretty close called [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336).

With your particular question though `patternProperties` is not really your main issue. In fact, I would argue that given the schema:

```
         "styles": {
            "title": "Style Definitions",
            "description": "Style definition",
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.*$": {
                    ...
                }
            }
         }
```

That the following interface really is a good translation:

```
interface Styles {
    [key: string]: ...,
}
```

So despite the title of your question, your *real* question has to do with implementing `oneOf` functionality from json schema into a typescript interface. There is no "1 to 1" equivalent in TS, and the answer really becomes very specific to what the actual definitions are of `Definition1` and `Definition2`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required).

**Addendum:**

The library I referenced, openapi-typescript, wrongly implements `oneOf` by using a TS union ([relevant code](https://github.com/drwpow/openapi-typescript/blob/main/src/transform/schema.ts#L71)). But as you observed, that is not correct. For example, the following is legal typescript:

```
interface First {
    aString: string;
    aNumber?: number;
}

interface Second {
    aString: string | boolean;
}

const tester: First | Second = {
    aString: 'asdgasdf'
}

console.log(tester);
```

but `tester` fulfills `First` AND `Second`, and so if this had been the jsonschema "equivalent" using `oneOf`, then `tester` would not have validated.