# String Pattern Validation in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, how to validate string pattern?
example const str = "ABC1-AB9"

1. max length should be 8
2. string pattern should be xxxx-xxx
3. x can be A-Z and 0-9 only

Comment: Have you try regex? [How to define a regex-matched string type in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445767/how-to-define-a-regex-matched-string-type-in-typescript)

Comment: do you want a regex to validate it or a type?

Comment: This is either a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51445767/438273) or you can use a regular expression [like this](https://regexr.com/6t3dl): `/^[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{3}$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
^[A-z0-9]{4}-[A-z0-9]{3} [0-9]{1}
```

This could be the regex you are looking for. You can test the same by going to https://regexr.com/ website and making your own custom regex.