# TypeScript error in @react-types/table/src/index.d.ts(18,41): Type expected. TS1110

Tags: reactjs, typescript

help with error, please

```
TypeScript error in @react-types/table/src/index.d.ts(18,41): Type expected.  TS1110
```

### Terminal

```
PS C:\Users\jonathas\projetos\portal-cliente-frontend> yarn start
    17 | /** Widths that result in a constant pixel value for the same Table width. */
  > 18 | export type ColumnStaticSize = number | `${number}` | `${number}%`; // match regex: /^(\d+)(?=%$)/
       |                                         ^
    19 | /** Widths that change size in relation to the remaining space and in ratio to other dynamic columns. */
    20 | export type ColumnDynamicSize = `${number}fr`; // match regex: /^(\d+)(?=fr$)/
    21 | /** All possible sizes a column can be assigned. */
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "portal-cliente-atem",
  "version": "0.1.101",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@adobe/react-spectrum": "^3.24.1",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^4.23.3",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@fontsource/montserrat": "^4.5.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "framer-motion": "^8.4.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.1",
    "inversify": "^5.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "notistack": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.1.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "start:prod": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='production' react-app-rewired start",
    "start:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired start",
    "build:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "types": [
    "node",
    "express"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "src/typings"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
}
```

Comment: Those aren’t types, those are interpolated strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448473/438992

Comment: Could u please share complete code.

Comment: unfortunately not, the code is private on github because it belongs to the company